# Merge bank-statements into proof-provenance-of-funds

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

There are several questions tagged [bank-statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bank-statements).  It appears that all of them are about submitting bank statements as part of a visa application, which should be covered under [proof-provenance-of-funds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-provenance-of-funds).  I suggest that these tags be merged.

Answer (score 2):

Your wish is my command :) Done!